# WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! using Bitbucket Pipelines and SSH

Tags: ssh, permissions, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm stating out with Git and attempting to use Bitbucket Pipelines to deploy to my remote server.

After reading a few posts on this and seeing what others have attempted, I am using the following code:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
    default:
        - step:
            script:
                - umask 077 - echo $MY_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa

                - scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -P $SERVER_PORT -r $DIRECTORY_TRANSFER_LIST $USERNAME@$SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:~/site
```

Just to point out, the Environment variables are:

DIRECTORY_TRANSFER_LIST: This is my Domain without www. i.e domain.co.uk

MY_SSH_KEY: I have tried both public and private keys but doesn't seem to make a difference.

SERVER_PORT: 22

I'm not actually sure what image means and why this link is here, this could be my issue?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

After readying another post regarding the same error message, although not to do with Bitbucket Pipelines. It was suggest to change the chmod to 400.

So I ssh's into the remote server and changed the permissions for id_rsa to 400:

```
cd ~/.ssh
chmod 400 id_rsa
```

But that didn't make any difference when I re-ran the pipeline.

What am I not doing?

Comment: what is the error message after the chmod?

Comment: Exactly the same which I find strange

Comment: Is the file you changed permissions of really /root/.ssh/id_rsa then?

Answer (score 2):

You write “I ssh's into the remote server” – and I think this is the problem, as it sounds you tried to fix permissions on the server to which the project is deployed. SSH checks the permissions on the *client* side, which in your case is the SSH key in the Docker image. Which means you simply have to add the `chmod` in your `script`, between `umask` and `scp`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add your SSH key to Pipelines by following the documentation here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html

That will remove the need for you to manage file permissions, makes it easier to rotate keys, and removes a fairly confusing command from your configuration. (Your team will love you for it!)

The `umask 077 - echo $MY_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa` approach was a workaround before Pipelines had proper SSH key support.